# An easy way to find unwrap() usages of Result only

Tags: rust, error-handling

In Rust two of the most commonly used enums, `Option` and `Result`, have a method with the same name `unwrap()`.  I'm not sure why Rust authors chose both enums to use the same method name - it's clear that both enums are somewhat similar, but that decision can make it harder to find all the usages of, say, `Result`'s method only. And I think in a Rust project it would be very useful if we could easily find all the places where we have `unwrap()` or something else that might panic. For example, if we start off with some proof-of-concept implementation that is OK to panic but later decide to properly handle errors.

`Option`'s `unwrap()` could also panic, of course, but usually we would have made sure that wouldn't be possible, so there is a clear difference, compared to `Result`, where we generally *expect* there might be an error. (Also, I know `Option`'s `unwrap()` can generally be avoided by using alternatives, but sometimes it does make code simpler.)

---

Update

It seems from the comments I should probably clarify why I said sometimes `Option`'s unwrapping should be considered safe. I guess an example would be best:

```
if o.is_none() {
    // ...
    return ...;
}
// ...
o.unwrap()   //  <--- Here I do NOT expect a None
```

Comment: It's unclear to my why you "would have made sure" that `Option::unwrap` isn't possible when you didn't do the same thing for `Result::unwrap` - there's not really any semantic difference between them. Hitting an `unwrap()` of either kind in production code should be considered a bug. Why do you consider `Result::unwrap` more worthy of debugging than `Option::unwrap`?

Comment: Easiest way is probably with [`rust-analyzer`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#find-all-references) in your favorite IDE.

Comment: There is the [`unwrap_used`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unwrap_used) lint in clippy, which is `allow` by default. It will trigger on both `Option` and `Result`, though. I agree with the other comments that the distinction implied in your question is uncalled for.

Comment: trentcl, the difference is that sometimes we might opt to deliberately rely on panics, for the sake of simplicity. As I wrote in the question:
"For example, if we start off with some proof-of-concept implementation that is OK to panic but later decide to properly handle errors."

Comment: "Result, where we generally expect there might be an error". Do you mean that you don't expect any Option you use to ever be "None" ?

Comment: OK, I'm gonna give you a more concrete example. Now I'm writing a rather simple app in Rust, which is intended to be called from a cron. It does some stuff and exits. Panics definitely seem to be the simplest way to go. I _know_ in theory one day I might make extend the app into a constantly running app that shouldn't panic, so then I might need to refactor. If (and only if) needed. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: SirDarius, if I have some code like `if v.is_some() { ......... }`, I *know* `v` cannot be `None`. So in those cases I will _not_ expect None. But if I run an SQL query, I will expect an `Err`.

Comment: In my opinion, it makes sense if we consider that there is a much higher cost associated to proper error handling compared to simple unwraps. In my experience with the language, this is not the case. Error propagation using the "?" operator is pretty straightforward, and the panic itself can be left to the "main" function which can return a Result.

Comment: `if v.is_some() { let foo = v.unwrap(); ... }` is a code smell, which tests _twice_ if the option is `Some` (once explicitly and once inside the `unwrap`) → so it should be replaced by `if let Some (foo) = v { ... }`

Comment: @at54321 Concerning your update: It would be more idiomatic to use [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html) (for example, like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=169ba85d2b0ea4aaa7613e918edaafa2)). Generally, while you *can* use `is_some()`/`is_none()` to check whether unwrapping would lead to a panic, there is almost always a more idiomatic way, be it `if let`, `match` or [the `?` try syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/enter_question_mark.html).

Comment: Elias, I know that and I totally agree that _usually_ there is a better way to do it. But here I am specifically referring to the cases when `is_none()` had already been handled somehow, so we already *know* we can safely `unwrap()`.

Comment: You can do the same thing with `Result::is_ok`/`is_err`, though, so my original question stands: why do you consider `Result` and `Option` to be different in this respect?

Comment: You should be able to forbid unwraps at the library level similar to how you can forbid unsafe code at the library level in my opinion. We should make it an optional compiler error.