# Should using .unwrap() be considered bad practice?

Tags: rust, error-handling

Seeing the comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314565/an-easy-way-to-find-unwrap-usages-of-result-only), made me wonder - should using `unwrap()` be considered bad practice?

In my view, sometimes unwrapping makes sense. At least in these two scenarios:

1. We *know* an `Option` value cannot be `None`, because we have already handled that case, earlier in the code. An example:

```
if o.is_none() {
    // do some stuff here...
    return ...;
}
// ...
o.unwrap()   //  <--- Here I do NOT expect a None
```

2. If we develop a simple short-lived tool, which is simply gonna end on error either way, relying on panics instead of "proper" error handling (with `Result`, `?`, etc.) could simplify code, more or less.

Obviously, sometimes relying on `unwrap()` might cause more harm than good, so it isn't quite obvious to me whether I should **always** refrain from using `unwrap()` or not? If not, **when** would it be OK to use `unwrap()`?

Comment: I would avoid using `unwrap` on values produced at runtime -- pattern matching is the right way to handle them. The only times you should `unwrap` are when you have compile time code that the compiler isn't smart enough to reason about, such as a hardcoded regex that you know is valid.

Answer (score 5):

> We know an Option value cannot be None, because we have already checked that case, earlier in the code. An example:
>
> ```rust
> if o.is_none() {
>     return ...;
> }
> // ...
> o.unwrap()   //  <--- Here I do NOT expect a None
> ```

While there are cases where this is unavoidable, the "correct" way to handle this is to use pattern-matching e.g.

```rust
let o = if let Some(o) = o {
    o
} else {
    return o;
}
```

or something along those lines.

There are cases where "unwrapping" is unnecessary, but in that case in production software I would use `expect` with a non-generic explanation, or an explicit `panic!` with a documentation of the assumption.

> If we develop a simple short-lived tool, which is simply gonna end on error either way, relying on panics instead of "proper" error handling (with Result, ?, etc.) could simplify code, more or less.

That wouldn't make it "good practice", that would just make it "I don't care about bad practices in that context".

It's a perfectly justifiable position, but it's not good practices.